# Can a Slaver Disintegrator destroy a General Products Hull?

Tags: known-space, ringworld

The books say that the hull is indestructible (except to Antimatter) and that it is immune to all known weapons.

But the books also say that the hull is a molecule, and that the Slaver Disintegrator disrupts the field that holds electrons to the nucleus. So it seems that the Disintegrator would be able to destroy the hull.

Answer (score 3):

For interest, this question is discussed a little bit in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/215tty/what_is_capable_of_destroying_a_general_products/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list) reddit thread but comes to no conclusion.

That said, yes, there is no reason a slaver disintegrator could not destroy a GP hull. As I recall, the time period when GP was still manufacturing hulls was before they had found the disintegrators, so it would have been true at that time. Nonetheless, as pointed out in Ringworld, they’re still the best.

Comment: Crashlander talks about Slaver Disintegrators and takes place before during and after the puppeteers leave

Comment: @lbenedetto I’ll need to doublecheck. I thought the stories that took place before the puppeteer exodus were before slaver disintegrators were mentioned. I don’t recall Beowulf ever discussing them.

Comment: It's a major plot point in the Beowulf story where he rescues the Kdatlyno

Comment: @lbenedetto but that took place after the puppeteers left Known Space, didn’t it? I don’t know if that matters tho. Ultimately, it destroys molecules by causing the atoms to tear themselves apart, and there is literally no indication that the hulls would be immune to such an action. As the Puppeteers themselves admit, it’s just a long-chained molecule.

Comment: Yeah, by about a year or two. They seem to be common knowledge how they work and are in the hands of at least rich people. The only indication I can find that they would be immune is that it says they're immune to all known weapons, and that the strength of the bonds are strengthened artificially with some sort of field. It's possible that field cancels the Slaver field

Comment: There’s a question- would it be considered a weapon or a tool? Because it’s mostly been used as part of the digging tool as I recall. Remember the- what was it called, the Kzin lesson?

Comment: Wunderland Treaty Maker. A giant version of the Slaver disintegrator with a second parallel beam also suppressing the charge on protons (as well as electrons). Created the naming feature on Slash/Canyon. A Slaver disintegrator was used to expose a stepping disk on the hull of the GP-3 *Hot Needle of Inquiry* in the second Ringworld novel after (protector) Teela Brown embedded it in poured lava, neither causing damage. The artificially strengthened atomic bounds of the hull not being effected by charge suppression. A puppeteer wouldn't bring a tool that could damage a GP hull.

Comment: @user22484 great point! You should write it as an answer tho- it’s far better than mine.